# Error in compareRaster(c(x, rasters)) : different extent

Tags: r, rgdal

I have a RasterStack that I want to add two rasters to.  I am using this code

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)

#original rasterstack
rasterfiles   <- list.files("C:\\path_to_rasters", "*.tif$", full.names = TRUE)

#stack the bands
stacked <- raster::stack(rasterfiles)

#read in new rasters
aspect <- raster("C:\\Aspect.tif")
slope <- raster("C:\\Slope.tif")


#create a shapefile extent of the stacked raster
e <- extent(stacked)

# coerce to a SpatialPolygons object
p <- as(e, 'SpatialPolygons') 

#assign crs
projection(p) <- crs(stacked)

#function to mask the raster
mask_raster <- function(raster, shape){
      outr <- crop(raster, extent(shape))
      outr <- mask(outr, p)
      return(outr)
}

#apply function
slope <- mask_raster(raster= slope, shape = p)

aspect <- mask_raster(raster= aspect, shape = p)



#add new layers to stack
stacked <- addLayer(stacked, aspect)
stacked <- addLayer(stacked, slope)
```

This works completely fine for `aspect` but for `slope` when I try to add the layer I get the following error:

```
Error in compareRaster(c(x, rasters)) : different extent
```

The crs of all rasters are identical.

Before trying to mask this is what is in each object:

`print(stacked)` returns:

```
class       : RasterStack 
dimensions  : 5629, 253, 1424137, 428  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 480524, 480777, 5220075, 5225704  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=14 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
names       :   Band_1,  Band_10, Band_100, Band_101, Band_102, Band_103, Band_104, Band_105, Band_106, Band_107, Band_108, Band_109,  Band_11, Band_110, Band_111, ... 
min values  :     0.00,    91.00,     0.00,     0.00,     0.00,     0.00,     0.00,     0.00,     0.00,     0.00,     0.00,     0.00,    80.00,     0.00,     0.00, ... 
max values  :  1914.00,  6061.00,  8805.00,  8830.00,  8745.00,  8455.00,  8230.00,  8317.00,  8092.00,  7945.00,  8124.00,  8122.00,  6160.00,  7642.00,  7222.00, ...
```

`print(aspect)` returns:

```
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 21152, 22837, 483048224  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 475140, 497977, 5212857, 5234009  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=14 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : C:\NEON_2\lidar\Aspect.tif 
names       : Aspect 
values      : 0, 360  (min, max)
```

`print(slope)` returns:

```
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 23239, 29315, 681251285  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 471887, 501202, 5211828, 5235067  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=14 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : C:\NEON_2\lidar\Slope.tif 
names       : Slope 
values      : 0, 65.33745  (min, max)
```

After I mask each object contains this:

`print(aspect)` returns:

```
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 5629, 253, 1424137  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 480524, 480777, 5220075, 5225704  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=14 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : Aspect 
values      : 0, 360  (min, max)
```

`print(slope)` returns:

```
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 5629, 253, 1424137  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 480524, 480777, 5220075, 5225704  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=14 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : Slope 
values      : 0.0285432, 39.09481  (min, max)
```

Comment: Could you please edit your post to include the error?

Comment: If i'm reading the code above correctly, your masking polygon will be the same size as the largest raster you have, so your masking function...extends the size of the raster? is that intentional? Might need to post the object summaries of both your inputs and outputs.

Comment: the extent in `stacked` is smaller than `slope` or `aspect`  I want to make `slope` and `aspect` fit to `stacked` so that I can add them as a band

Comment: Ah ok, I see now. If you open all these layers in a GIS and make them a bit transparent, do the cells all line up perfectly? Zoom right in and check the corners. Anyway in your function, try wrapping `extent(shape)` in `alignExtent(., stacked)` - might need to use the option `snap = 'in'` too. Makes the cropping polygon line up with the nearest raster cell edges.

Comment: `slope <- alignExtent(stacked, slope, snap='in')` returned `Error in alignExtent(stacked, slope, snap = "in") : 
  object should inherit from BasicRaster` but the same code worked fine with `aspect`

Comment: Ok, per your GIS recomendation, the cells in  `slope` are offset from those in `aspect`.  `aspect` perfectly overlays `stacked`.  This must be why, I will have to figure out a way to snap `slope` to the other rasters

Comment: Instead of using `crop` and `mask` to make your 2 rasters the same size of the stack, you better use `raster::resample` with `method='ngb'` if you are sure they are aligned: `slope_res <- resample(slope, stacked)`. I also recommend you not to overwrite your original variable names, like `slope` becoming `slope` with different extents and so...

Comment: `resample` is fine, but `ngb` is only appropriate for categorical data; use `bilinear` for these datasets. For aspect, be aware that either method can produce some wierdness since the data is circular. The better approach is to resample the source DEM and then recalculate aspect, or use trigonometry to convert aspect to a linear scale (northness or eastness) before resampling.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in R, it was an error while assigning the correct directory. Upon setting valid directory query ran successfully.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).